# org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ObjectId has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradlew, jgit

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'xxx'.
> Could not create task ':prepareRelease'.
   > Could not create task of type 'GitReleaseTask'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type GitReleaseTask.
         > org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ObjectId has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

GitReleaseTask.groovy is groovy task which use org.eclipse.jgit library from gradle.
I get the above exception while am building my project. I have also noticed jgit v5.13 in classpath of my project currently. The build was successful till few days back and all of the sudden it fails. My guess is that jgit v5.13 is built using advanced versions of Java and we are using Java8 to build our project.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: 55 is Java 11... jgit 6.x requires Java 11. Are you sure jgit 6 hasn't snuck into your dependencies? A build scan would show https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html

Comment: As jgit 6 came out on the 29th November, I would bet you have a wildcard dependency on it, and haven't specified a specific version https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit

Comment: configurations {
        all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'org.eclipse.core:commands:3.3.0-I20070605-0010'
                force 'org.eclipse.equinox:common:3.6.200-v20130402-150
                force 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.5.0.201909110433-r'            }
        }
    }
Also added under dependencyManagement as follows
dependency 'org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.5.0.201909110433-r'

But still it's not working, somehow it's picking version 6

Comment: You will need to use a build scan or one of the cmd-line techniques in the link in the second comment to work out what

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your **JAVA version to 11**

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
59 = Java 15
60 = Java 16
61 = Java 17
62 = Java 18
63 = Java 19
64 = Java 20
65 = Java 21
```

Also,**strong text** **upgrade jgit depedency**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1.202309021850-r</version>
    </dependency>
```